# 2004-LCD with PCF8574-I2C and wiringPi (Python)

Tags: gpio, python, i2c, wiringpi

I try to interface my 2004-LCD display with wiringPi (in Python 3). The display is connected to a PCF8574-chip, so I need to use I2C.

This is my test code:

```
import wiringpi2 as wiringpi

wiringpi.wiringPiSetupSys();

af_base = 100

af_rs = af_base + 0
af_e = af_base + 2
af_db4 = af_base + 4
af_db5 = af_base + 5
af_db6 = af_base + 6
af_db7 = af_base + 7

af_backlight = af_base + 3

def backlight_on():
    wiringpi.digitalWrite(af_backlight, 1)

def backlight_off():
    wiringpi.digitalWrite(af_backlight, 0)

wiringpi.pcf8574Setup(af_base, 0x27)

lcd_handle = wiringpi.lcdInit(4, 20, 4, af_rs, af_e, af_db4, af_db5, af_db6, af_db7, 0, 0, 0, 0)

backlight_on()

wiringpi.lcdPrintf(lcd_handle, "Hello World!")
```

The code runs without any errors. The backlight on the LCD first turns out and then turns on again, when I run `backlight_on()`.

*However, the text doesn't show up on the display.*

To check if the LCD or the I2C-chip is damaged, I followed the instructions from [this website](http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog/?p=4849).

Now comes the strange part:
*When I now run the test code from above again, it works without any hassle.*

It seems, the other project loads some stuff which is essential for controlling the LCD.

What is missing in my test code to interface the LCD in the first place?

Comment: Presumably the other set of code is doing some required initialisation.

Comment: @joan I also think so. However, I looked through the other code and didn't find anything special...

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem. I did some research and found out the following code works. I don't know why it works but it just works. Add the following to the beginning of your script:

```
port=1   # Depends on your pi rev. Run i2cdetect to find out
bus = smbus.SMBus(port)
bus.write_byte_data(self.i2caddr, self.port, 0x28 >> 4)
bus.write_byte_data(self.i2caddr, self.port, 0x28 & 0x0F)
bus.write_byte_data(self.i2caddr, self.port, 0x0)
```

Also you might want to force the RW pin to be LOW:

```
af_rw = pinbase + 1
wiringpi.pinMode(af_rw, 1)
wiringpi.digitalWrite(af_rw, 0)
```

Comment: Update: just these two lines will work,
`bus = smbus.SMBus(port)
bus.write_byte_data(self.i2caddr, self.port, 0x0)`

Answer (score 1):

The python code in this page works fine, just follow all the directions there:
http://hardware-libre.fr/2014/03/en-raspberry-pi-using-a-4x20-characters-display/

to find the address of your pcf8574 (in my case it is pcf8574AT therefore the address is 0x3f), once you get it, change the value in the python code, get a terminal screen and execute the following command:
sudo ./i2cdetect -y 1

Good luck !